# Git 1.7.9.5 Upgrade to current release of GIT 2.x on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, git

I'm currently on ubuntu 12.04 and since this is an older version of ubuntu i have git 1.7.9.5 installed and i'm not sure how i can upgrade this to git 2.x.

- what do i type to install git 2.x (sudo apt-get install git)?
- when installing git 2.x, does it overwrite git 1.7? if not how do you choose which one to use?
- how do i find out where git 1.7 is installed on my system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the `add-apt-repository` command doesn't work, you need to add the `python-software-properties` package first. Combined you would do:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git --version
```

Comment: You also need to run `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common` for `apt-add-repository` to work.

Answer (score 16):

There is a [Git PPA at launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) where the latest releases are made available as packages. Thus to get the latest stable version do as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

After that you will have Git 2.x installed and the 1.7.x version removed.