# Upgrade Git version on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, git

Can please somebody tell me what is wrong with this?

I run

```
$ sudo apt-get purge git; sudo apt-get autoremove; sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  git-man liberror-perl
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  git* git-core*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 21.0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 81533 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing git-core (1:1.9.1-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing git (1:2.2.2-0ppa1~ubuntu10.04.1) ...
Purging configuration files for git (1:2.2.2-0ppa1~ubuntu10.04.1) ...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  git-man liberror-perl
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1,831 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 80929 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing git-man (1:2.2.2-0ppa1~ubuntu10.04.1) ...
Removing liberror-perl (0.17-1.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  git-man liberror-perl
Suggested packages:
  git-daemon-run git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-email git-gui gitk
  gitweb git-arch git-cvs git-mediawiki git-svn
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  git git-man liberror-perl
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/11.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 22.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Selecting previously unselected package liberror-perl.
(Reading database ... 80751 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../liberror-perl_0.17-1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking liberror-perl (0.17-1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package git-man.
Preparing to unpack .../git-man_1%3a2.2.2-0ppa1~ubuntu10.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking git-man (1:2.2.2-0ppa1~ubuntu10.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package git.
Preparing to unpack .../git_1%3a2.2.2-0ppa1~ubuntu10.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking git (1:2.2.2-0ppa1~ubuntu10.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up liberror-perl (0.17-1.1) ...
Setting up git-man (1:2.2.2-0ppa1~ubuntu10.04.1) ...
Setting up git (1:2.2.2-0ppa1~ubuntu10.04.1) ...
```

After that `$ git --version` shows:

```
git version 1.8.2.1
```

It looks like git 2.x was installed but I can continue getting the old version.

**Updates:**

- I have already tried this: [Git 1.7.9.5 Upgrade to current release of GIT 2.x on ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/571549/git-1-7-9-5-upgrade-to-current-release-of-git-2-x-on-ubuntu-12-04)
- `dpkg -L git` see: https://gist.github.com/montogeek/e7bedaf03cef9a3d969b
- `which git`:  /usr/local/bin/git

Comment: Please edit your post and add the output of `dpkg -L git` and `which git`.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You need to add the Git Maintainers repository in order to get the latest Git version.

Please run these commands in order:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

Then, check the version of the installed Git:

```
git --version
```

It's not always necessary to remove the existing Git before upgrading it, but if you run into any problems, do the following and then repeat the steps mentioned above:

```
sudo apt-get remove git
```

Comment: I managed to upgrade without removing git first (I did not run `sudo apt-get remove git`)

Comment: I think it is unnecessary to remove git. I upgraded (from Ubuntu 14.04's version) without removing it

Comment: @glarrain I wrote that line as a precaution against any kind of data corruption.

Comment: i have a corporate vmware virtual desktop running ubuntu 14 and it tells me - cannot add ppa, please check format....

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on Windows 10 (using Windows Subsystem for Linux). This method worked perfectly in it too. As of now (March 2020), I got Git v2.25.1.

Answer (score 4):

You have a second copy of git installed in `/usr/local/bin` which is being used instead of the system installed git.

Without knowing how the other git has been installed, I would say that you need to manually remove the other git binary from `/usr/local/bin`.