# Cannot upgrade git to the latest version in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, ppa, git

I follow the steps in [Upgrade Git version on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/579589/upgrade-git-version-on-ubuntu-14-04), but when I enter the first step command: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa`, I receive the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/git-core-ppa-trusty.list'
```

you can check the following picture for detail:

[image: error discription]

With this error, when I continue to enter the remaining 2 commands, I failed to upgrade my git version. Hope someone know this problem can help me out, thank you.

Comment: Can you check if the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` exists on your machine? Also please copy and paste command outputs as plain text and with code formatting instead of uploading screenshots. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your formating, but with my current reputation, I can just uploading screenshots, sorry for the inconvenient. I manually create the directory of `source.list.d`, and the above error disappeared, but when I enter the second command: `sudo apt-get update`, I receive the following error: `Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch`.

Comment: @Phymin you don't need to upload anything. Just copy the output and paste it here.

Comment: @muru The editor blocks posting more than 2 or 3 links for new users. If the output is not formatted as code block, possible URLs inside it count as links too. The solution is to highlight the output in the editor and use the code format button **`{}`** or press Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial error (the Python `FileNotFoundError`) is most likely caused because the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` inside which `add-apt-repository` tries to create a sources file does not exist, for whatever obscure reason.

To fix this, simply create this directory manually with e.g. this command:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work for me, the error remains the same as before.

Comment: Then please update your question with the exact command and full output.

Comment: Some comments on the answer to the linked question suggest you may additionally have to change your update server, *eg, from us.ubuntu.com to XX.ubuntu.com where XX is your country code* – could you try that please? Also try `sudo apt clean` after removing the files.

Comment: Huh, you get a hash sum mismatch on *all* repositories? That is weird. While I try to find something appropriate, you could indeed try switching to a different mirror server as dessert described.

Comment: Could you simply try the other answers to the [linked question](https://askubuntu.com/q/41605/367990)? Maybe even waiting a few hours could solve it. I don't really know what else to try right now.

Comment: Hi, I tried a lot of mirrors, the above hash sum mismatch was copied from the main server. but with all these mirrors, the hash sum match of the ppa:git-core never passed. And I also tried the other answers in the linked question, but they all didn't work.

Comment: Well, I don't know how to proceed then. I would suggest to split your question up though. More precisely, I'd recommend you to remove everything Hash Sum mismatch related from your question (and I will do for the answer) so that only the FileNotFoundError remains, which is solved by this answer so that you could accept it. Then you post a new question about the Hash Sum mismatch error and include your full `sudo apt update` output as well as all possible solutions that you tried already, with a link to that question where you found them. That way more people will see it and might respond.

Comment: Hi, I switched  to another network and the upgrade succeeded, thanks for your help, it really helps.

Comment: Yay, cool. Glad you got it to work :)